# What is the status of the impossibility of metaphysics?

Tags: metaphysics, kant, ontology

[SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaphysics/#MetPos) describes the thesis that metaphysics is impossible as follows:

> Let us call the thesis that all metaphysical statements are meaningless “the strong form” of the thesis that metaphysics is impossible. (At one time, an enemy of metaphysics might have been content to say that all metaphysical statements were false. But this is obviously not a possible thesis if the denial of a metaphysical statement must itself be a metaphysical statement) And let us call the following statement the “weak form” of the thesis that metaphysics is impossible: metaphysical statements are meaningful, but human beings can never discover whether any metaphysical statement is true or false (or probable or improbable or warranted or unwarranted).

The strong thesis seems to refute itself, because any statement about the impossibility of metaphysical truth is itself a metaphysical truth.

What about the weak form of the thesis that metaphysics is impossible? Kant [seems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-metaphysics/) to echo this view, but I'm wondering of the current status of this thesis. SEP does not go into detail about this. Much of metaphysics apparently relies on general principles of rationality, such as simplicity, but it's not clear to me how we can apply these here. Of course, we can *believe* that such rationality is "good", in a general sense, but we really have no justification for it. While rationality may be justified in the sense that it is pragmatic for us in our present situation, I don't see how *any* principle of rationality can be used metaphysically.

So, what is the status of this thesis within the philosophical community? Have most metaphysicians accepted that they deal with purely (to borrow a term) *possible worlds* without any relation to the *actual world*, or do they assert that we can determine metaphysical truths in our present condition?

Comment: i think you've misunderstood the quote: which seems to claim that the strong thesis is only about impossibility, not falsity. if the latter, then it would be enough to show that it is a metaphysical statement (though i'm not sure how anyone can show that in the abstract) to show it is incoherent. but, instead, it has to be shown that the thesis *depends upon* metaphysical statements, that no meaningful case can be made for it. quite why the incoherence of the basis is more difficult to show than the thesis, i'm not sure (though as stated i'm not sure why the latter is said to be easy)

Comment: it seems that 'metaphysics' includes **refutations** of metaphysical theses. but surely one could counter that, no, 'metaphysics' *proper* always advances a thesis that is not just a refutation. this may be anti-intellectual and gauche, to treat it in the abstract, outside the dialectic etc. of evolving positions. but it is not open to the charge of self referential incoherence to the same extent as LP, as the LP's would have had to find another type of meaning to avoid incoherence. rather than merely using 'denial' assumed by the strong thesis already

Comment: i don't see any problem with a claim like *there are no true non negative existential metaphysical statements*. not in the **abstract**, without reasons for supposing it. i'm ranting, and may seem incoherent.

Comment: Big M metaphysics, discerning the nature of reality by reason alone, or by some extraordinary intuition, is now largely confined to religious discourse. Small m metaphysics, pragmatic and fallible, that covers speculative aspects of inquiry is very much alive, and undergoes a revival, see [What are some real-life applications of metaphysics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/32915/9148) One does not need "real justification" of metaphysical speculations as long as they are put to work to unify knowledge or generate conjectures, judged as fruitful or not, adjusted, etc.

Comment: @Conifold Isn't there some middle ground here? For example, the mind-body problem. It isn't quite as pragmatic as something like formal ontologies in computer science, but not quite as " purely metaphysical" as religious discussions. Or, again, is this simply a discussion about possible worlds? Also, I'd fully expect this to be a topic of debate mainly in the context of religion, so it's not entirely clear to me why that's significant.

Comment: "Pragmatic" does not mean narrowly practical or directly applicable. The mind-body discussions develop ideas and conceptions that are viable given what we already know, and help sort out the general picture. But they are all subject to revision based on how they perform, hence judged pragmatically.

Comment: @Conifold Yes, I certainly agree with that. I guess my question is how much like science this is. Science may not have a purely reason-based justification, but nonetheless it is extremely useful and (almost) everyone believes in its power as a methodology. If this is the case with metaphysics, I think this matches with SEP's definition of the "weak form," which is to say "theory X may seem more plausible than theory Y, but we admit that it is difficult to say that theory X is more 'probable' or 'warranted' than Y" (to borrow SEP terminology). Is this the case, or is there more nuance here?

Comment: Science focuses on issues where broad consensus can be had because empirical evidence appeals to basic perceptions that most humans share. Alas, in many fields those can not settle issues, and vaguer measures of success are far more controversial. So it can not possibly be the case with metaphysics.

Comment: @Conifold This may be a bit of a semantics issue, but that's the essence of SEP's "weak thesis," correct? As in, it is essentially impossible to reach any universal conclusions in metaphysics (or even probabilstic conclusions)?

Comment: In addition to strong and weak form of "metaphysics is wrong" there is a third form which we may call the anti-historical form. This [answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/53963/37256) by Mr.Kennedy gives a good rendering of it (as I spell out in the comments) in his second last para. Ironically he doesn't wish to see through the clear separation!

Comment: The "weak thesis" is that human mind can not reach metaphysical conclusions in a reliable way, which is still very strong. This is just an empirical observation that they are bound to be controversial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Borchert's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedia_of_Philosophy) entry on metaphysics , metaphysics is the act of attempting to account for the "fundamental nature of being", and is "concerned with the contours of the categories of entity postulated or presupposed" real or imagined to encompass "a complete, coherent ontology, embracing all that is necessary to capture the correct account of the world".

First, there is no monolithic philosophical community. Many communities of philosophers exist, and they may hold widely divergent views of the world and the state of 'philosophy' whatever that may be. I know of no statistic which would be required to actually answer your question (coming from a doctrine of empiricism), but I would argue that most metaphysicians believe their work has some relevance to objective (intersubjective, physical, actual,...) reality. Here's a journal of metaphysics [Metaphysics Metaphysics Collaborative](https://metaphysicsjournal.com/) which contains an article on William of Ockham's views on the Aristotelian ontological status of artifacts [“Nothing in Nature Is Naturally a Statue”: William of Ockham on Artifacts](https://metaphysicsjournal.com/articles/10.5334/met.7/). It has long been the hallmark of metaphysics to engage in debate over what is the proper relation between ontology and epistemology, for instance, and ontology and epistemology have a direct bearing on "reality".

The nature of metaphysical discourse has evolved necessarily since the time of Aristotle, and a number of philosophical problems and approaches have arisen. Borchert's cites a spectrum of responses of differing ontological commitment: from [realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/realism/) to [antirealism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-realism/#AntiFoilForScieReal), for instance. Metaphysics is a continuing dialog that discusses ideas such as the universal and the particular.

It is certainly a hallmark of metaphysics that it is rationalist far more than it is empirical in content, but remember that of the most natural of the three logical methods of inference (deduction, induction, and [abduction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abduction/)), metaphysics relies, like all philosophy on intuition and meaning, both ideas that are only recently coming to light (historically speaking) in terms of cognitive processes. While the edifice of Western philosophy has relied heavily on the scientific method, science itself has discerned that the way in which philosophers think is itself subject to forces and rules. (See the cognitive science discipline of [cognitive semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_semantics))

Philosophy has often been disparaged by scientists ([Bill Nye and philosophy](https://qz.com/960303/bill-nye-on-philosophy-the-science-guy-says-he-has-changed-his-mind/)) as being unpragmatic and excessively rational, in the same way metaphysics has been seen by some philosophers. But the obvious truth is, that when reasoning from first principle, it is necessary to select first principles, and how is that to be done? Modern psychology has shown that rational decisions are rooted in the limbic system anyway. (See the historical evolution from Euclidean to non-Euclidean geometries from the field of the philosophy of mathematics to see an evolution in metaphysical thinking).

Philosophers who have engaged in metaphysical speculation since Kant have included A.J. Ayer, among others. While there are many brilliant rejections of metaphysics, the fact seems to be that metaphysics serves as a useful category and a pragmatic function for the majority of philosophers and continues as vibrant source of debate. There are many justifications for metaphysics, including those supported by cognitive science. Whether or not you buy a rejection is largely a result of your metaphysical presuppositions.